# My extjs app is coming up blank

Tags: extjs

My app comes up blank. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for helping.

Here is my application.js:

```
Ext.application({
    name: "GiipIq",
    appFolder: "app",
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    //controllers: ['Problems']
});
```

Here is my Viewport:
    Ext.define("GiipIq.view.Viewport", {
        extend: "Ext.container.Viewport",
        layout: "fit",
        requires: ["GiipIq.view.Problem"],

```
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [{
            xtype: "problemwindow"
        }];
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Here is my view (Prolblem.js):

```
Ext.define("GiipIq.view.Problem", {
    extend: "Ext.window.Window",
    alias: "widget.problemwindow",
    title: "Problems to be run",
    closable: false,
    layout: "border",

    getEastPanel: function() {
        return {
            region: "west",
            title: "Available Problems",
            width: 200,
            split: true,
            collapsible: true,
            floatable: false,
            xtype: "panel",
            rootVisible: false,
            store: store
        };
    },

    getCentralPanel: function() {
        return {
        };
    },

    initComponent: function () {
        this.items = [
            this.getEastPanel(),
            //this.getCentralPanel()
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 3):

When you just get a white screen and nothing meaningful in FireBug (I assume you are using it) **it's because there is a mismatch between the name of your class and the name of your file, or between the name defined for our app GiipIq and the definition of one of your classes**, look very closely. Don't get frustrated white screen 98% of the times is a mismatch.

Best regards. @code4jhon

Comment: I injected this line (console.log("inside getEastPanel");) at the top of getEastPanel() function, and I can see it in Firebug. So, the right file and function do get called.

Comment: I injected this line (console.log(this.items) after this.items in initComponent, and can see my objects([Object { region="west", title="Available Problems", width=200, more...}, Object {}]). So, the right file and function do get called. Other than that, there is no error whatsoever.

Comment: 1.- I wouldn't add a window as an item of a Viewport. Use mywindow.show() 2.- Just use initComponent if you know what it is for and what is the difference between putting there the items against as a class config. 3.- Start simple add a simple panel to your Viewport and make sure you can see that, you can grow from there...